# Weird result coverting from varchar to varbinary and converting back -- sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, context-info

Here is the stored procedure:

```
     CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestTestTest AS  
       BEGIN
         DECLARE @ProcedureIdForTracking varbinary(128) = CONVERT(varbinary(128), @@procid)
         DECLARE @ProcedureNameForTracking varbinary(128) = CONVERT(varbinary(128), OBJECT_NAME(@@procid))
         SELECT @@procid AS originalProcid, @ProcedureIdForTracking, CONVERT(bigint, @ProcedureIdForTracking) AS ConvertBackId
         SELECT OBJECT_NAME(@@procid) AS originalName, @ProcedureNameForTracking, CONVERT(varchar(1000),
     @ProcedureNameForTracking) AS ConvertBackName
         SET CONTEXT_INFO @ProcedureNameForTracking 
       END
```

I can recover the @@procid from the converting, but not the stored procedure name. Any idea?Anything wrong with the OBJECT_NAME function?

The result:
 [image]

Comment: It's not really that weird, you're taking an `nvarchar` string, converting it to `varbinary`, then converting that to `varchar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object names are of the datatype `SYSNAME` (A synonym for `NVARCHAR(128)`), you are therefore converting from one datatype to binary then back to another, so you are not doing the reverse. You can demonstrate this fairly simply:

```
DECLARE @ProcName SYSNAME = 'dbo.TestTestTest'
DECLARE @VarBin VARBINARY(128) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), @Procname);


SELECT  Inccorect = CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), @VarBin),
        Correct = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), @VarBin);
```

Which yields:

```
Inccorect   Correct
------------------------------
d           dbo.TestTestTest
```

Furthermore, `NVARCHAR` requires 2 bytes per character, so `VARBINARY(128)` is not long enough to store it, again, this can be demonstrated:

```
DECLARE @ProcName SYSNAME = REPLICATE('|', 128);
DECLARE @VarBin VARBINARY(128) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), @Procname);

SELECT  Len1 = LEN(@ProcName),
        Len2 = LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), @VarBin));
```

Which gives:

```
Len1    Len2
-----------------
128     64
```

So in you would need to adjust your types and lengths:

```
DECLARE @ProcedureIdForTracking varbinary(128) = CONVERT(varbinary(128), @@procid)
DECLARE @ProcedureNameForTracking varbinary(256) = CONVERT(varbinary(128), OBJECT_NAME(@@procid))
SELECT @@procid AS originalProcid, @ProcedureIdForTracking, CONVERT(bigint, @ProcedureIdForTracking) AS ConvertBackId
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(@@procid) AS originalName, @ProcedureNameForTracking, CONVERT(nvarchar(128),
 @ProcedureNameForTracking) AS ConvertBackName
SET CONTEXT_INFO @ProcedureNameForTracking
```